# number formatting in foreach statement of tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach

I have the following code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \i [evaluate=\i as \ii using \i+5] in {1,2,3,4} {
    \node at (\i,0) {\ii};
}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I like to print `6 7 8 9`, but the above code prints `6.0 7.0 8.0 9.0`.  How can I control the precision in the evaluate statement?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the `\pgfmathprintnumber{\ii}` instead of `\ii`. See Section 66 in the PGF/TikZ manual for more information about the syntax.

Comment: You could also say `evaluate=\i as \ii using int(\i+5)`, then `\ii` will hold just the integer part.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`numprint`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/numprint) package, and say:

```
\nprounddigits{0}\numprint{\ii}
```

An alternative is the number printing facility of the [`siunitx`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/siunitx) package. You have the `\num` macro, usable as follows:

```
\sisetup{round-mode = places}% in preamble    
\num[round-precision=0]{\ii}
```