# number format in \pgfmathsetmacro for auto-foldernaming in tikz \foreach environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach, pgfmath

What I want to do is creating automatically the filenames of the datafiles inside a foreachloop in tikz. Maybe it's better to show a minimal example first:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots,pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotstableset{%
    col sep=semicolon,
    x index=0,
    y index=1,
}
\usetikzlibrary{fpu}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{(TA0.04)(T0.08).txt}
1;1
2;2
3;3
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{(TA0.04)(T0.09).txt}
2;1
3;2
5;3
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{(TA0.04)(T0.10).txt}
4;1
5;2
8;3
\end{filecontents}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\TA{0.04}
\begin{axis}[xlabel=$x$, ylabel=$y$]
    \foreach \A in {0.04,0.05,0.06} {
        \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu,/pgf/fpu/output format=fixed}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\T}{\TA+\A}
        \pgfmathroundtozerofill{\T}
        \addplot table {(TA\TA)(T\T).txt};
    }
\end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Inside this little tikz picture I want to do the following (and I have to do this for quite a big set of datafiles and different starting values).

- First I want to define a starting value for \TA which I've done with \def...
- Given the list of looping numbers i want to calculate for each loop a now variable \T which represents the sum of \TA and the current looping variable \A
- Now, given this three numbers I want to load my data from my datafile (see preamble for filenames)

**And here is my problem...**

When the sum is equal to *0.10* I get the error:

... Could not read table file '(TA0.04)(T0.1).txt'. ...

because the value of \T is *0.1* and not *0.10*.

Each numbers in my filenames have exactly two digits, but sometimes the last one is a  zero as shown above. I tried to fix this with `\pgfmathroundtozerofill{\T}` but it does not work.

Has anybody an idea how I can fix this problem?? How can I fix the number of digits or add this zeros to the number???

P.S.
Title seems to be the same than  [number formatting in foreach statement of tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45172/number-formatting-in-foreach-statement-of-tikz), but this question didn't helped me. Therefor I started a now one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You almost had it, you only have to use `\pgfmathresult` instead of `\T` in your `\addplot` command. That's because `\pgfmathroundtozerofill` doesn't alter the contents of `\T`, but rather saves the result in `\pgfmathresult`.